# Optimizing Windows 7 for SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have Windows 7 RC1 running on a solid-state-drive (SSD) on my laptop. I've seen various [recommendations](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx) for tuning the OS to take advantage of the SSD. There are a few obvious ones, such as disabling defragmentation, and some controversial, such as disabling page file. Thought that this would be a perfect place to gather peer-reviewed advice.

Comment: We've written a post about this on the Super User Blog, see [Maximizing the lifetime of your SSD](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/).

Answer (score 13):

Serverfault has some info on this:

- [Any benefit or detriment from removing a pagefile on an 8GB RAM machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/23621/any-benefit-or-detriment-from-removing-a-pagefile-on-an-8gb-ram-machine/23684#23684)
- [System drive on SSD; pagefile to its own drive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/57452/system-drive-on-ssd-pagefile-to-its-own-drive)
- [Should you disable page file with SSD?](https://serverfault.com/questions/23720/should-you-disable-page-file-with-ssd)

And [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx) from Microsoft is quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the biggest one is just to wait; SSDs as primary drives are a pretty new phenomenon, and I know that the Windows 7 team is working on optimizations for SSD drives.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update: recently, I built another new system at work for a customer, with an SSD and an HDD. Windows 7 automatically moved the page file to the hard drive during setup, so that shouldn't be an issue anymore if you also have a hard drive