# Best practices - New Install of Windows 7 with SSD

Tags: windows-7, installation, ssd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Optimizing Windows 7 for SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/2980/optimizing-windows-7-for-ssd)

I'm building my first Windows 7 machine.  It will have a 128GB SSD and 1TB hard drive.  I'd like to make Windows 7 re-installation easy while getting the right stuff on the SSD vs. the hard drive. Any pointers would be appreciated, this is all new territory to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimizing Windows 7 for SSD](http://superuser.com/questions/2980/optimizing-windows-7-for-ssd) and [Best SSD tweaks for Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/137817/best-ssd-tweaks-for-windows-7), [What directories in a Windows 7 SSD...](http://superuser.com/questions/95862/what-directories-in-a-windows-7-ssd-install-would-you-link-junction-to-an-hdd) and [Minimize writes to SSD disks with Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/147734/minimize-writes-to-ssd-disks-with-windows-7)

Comment: We've written a post about this on the Super User Blog, see [Maximizing the lifetime of your SSD](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/).

Comment: My concern was more about what to put on the SSD vs the HDD and less about the care and feeding of SSD's.  More of a small fast drive vs large slow drive issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hard drive should only be used for storage or low I/O softwares : the Office Suite for example, doesn't need to be on an SSD; To the contrary, Photoshop or the latest games would benefit from the SSD.

As said by [Jeff Atwood](https://superuser.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) [on his blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html), SSD are more subject to failure than HDD, so backup regularly !

Comment: Well, this accepted answer didn't age well.

Answer (score 0):

For a SSD you could disable the "Prefetch" service from your services.msc. With SSD you wont need prefetching as defrag (which you can disable too).